# StackOverflow with DataStateBehavior and MVVM binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, data-binding, stack-overflow

In an Windows Phone 8 Silverlight application, I am using `DataStateBehavior` to show the data bound list item in a different style when my ViewModel property changes. The problem is the property in Question is set during the constructor of the ViewModel. Now while loading of the `ListBox` it goes into an infinite loop resulting in an Stack Overflow.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Trips}"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                         SelectionMode="Multiple">
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                    Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding"
                                    Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                    Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                                    Value="Top" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                                        Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                                             To=".5"
                                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                             Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected" />
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BackEndStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="IsNormal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="IsSelected">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                                        Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                <ec:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                                                      Value="True"
                                                                      TrueState="IsSelected"
                                                                      FalseState="IsNormal" />
                                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                                        <ec:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}"
                                                             MethodName="ToggleIsSelected" />
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TripName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime, Mode=OneWay}"
                                           Grid.Row="1" />
                                <Line Height="1"
                                      Grid.Row="2"
                                      Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                                      Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

As you can see, I have removed the `StoryBoard` for the original Selected state. I have a new set of visual states, and that is triggered by the `DataStateBehavior`.

Now when I try to run this, I get an stackoverflow while trying to render the listbox. The stack frames are full of this pattern. Looks like when `DataStateBehavior` sets the state, it triggers an apply template, and it repeats the whole evaluation cycle.

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_ApplyTemplate(System.Windows.FrameworkElement frameworkElement)   Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Control.ApplyTemplate()   Unknown
microsoft.expression.interactions.DLL!Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.VisualStateUtilities.GoToState(System.Windows.FrameworkElement element, string stateName, bool useTransitions) Unknown
microsoft.expression.interactions.DLL!Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.DataStateBehavior.Evaluate()  Unknown
microsoft.expression.interactions.DLL!Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.DataStateBehavior.OnBindingChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject obj, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object oldValue, object newValue)  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, System.Windows.DependencyObject.ValueOperation operation)  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp)   Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.System.Windows.IDataContextChangedListener.OnDataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.WeakDataContextChangedListener.MentorDataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)   Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnTreeParentUpdated(System.Windows.DependencyObject newParent, bool bIsNewParentAlive)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateTreeParent(MS.Internal.IManagedPeer oldParent, MS.Internal.IManagedPeer newParent, bool bIsNewParentAlive, bool keepReferenceToParent)  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.ManagedPeerTreeUpdate(System.IntPtr oldParentElement, System.IntPtr parentElement, System.IntPtr childElement, byte bIsParentAlive, byte bKeepReferenceToParent, byte bCanCreateParent)    Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

Can anyone think of a way to prevent this infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out this is one more idiosyncrasies of .Net now a days, where [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj682991(v=vs.105).aspx) is not clear enough, and leaves a lot to be "figure out". After a lot of trials, I found that the behavior works if the bound value is null when it loads. So I ended up changing my property to `bool?` (Nullable bool) instead of simple `bool`, set it to Null during constructor, and implemented a delay load logic to set to true/false. Now it does not result in StackOverFLow.

If someone wants to give it a try, please use the sample project from http://1drv.ms/1D8l6yS it has both problem version as well as fixed version.